# Vulkan Ghosting when using VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR

Tags: c, vulkan

I have a small sample, written in C using the Vulkan API. 
I followed the guide [vulkan-tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com) up to the end of the Uniform Buffers chapter.
While this tutorial is written in C++, I am using plain C, thus my codes differs slightly in some places.
In addition I have opted to use `DynamicState` instead of recreating the entire GraphicsPipeline each time the window is resized. In addition I changed both to always use `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR`.
It seems that I made some mistake adapting the code, because I get a lot of ghosting and choppiness from the rotating quad, as can be seen here: [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDBXB.jpg).
The left is my result and on the right is the original.

Theories and observations:

- It seems, that my one updates much slower, like at half framerate. But I measured that the UBOs are updated at the same frequency as in the original.
- Another cause could have been, that Swapchain Images are rendered in the wrong order. Like old images are being presented without being rerendered. I tried to rule out any synchronization problems by calling `vkDeviceWaitIdle` in each iteration of the main loop. It did not improve the situation.
- If you look closely, you can see that the original has a little amount of ghosting as well. I think this can be attributed to the monitor. It does not explain why the issue is so much more pronounced with my program.
- I reverted back to non dynamic Viewports, Scissors and turned resizing off altogether, to rule it out. It was not the cause.
- The C code uses cglm as opposed to glm. I have swapped glm out in the original. It is not the cause.
- An interesting observation: when the window is resized quickly, the issue goes away for the duration of the resize operation.

I have searched quite extensively for the problem. But haven't found anything. I don't really expect to debug my [code](https://gitlab.com/YmiYugy/vulkan-tutorial-c/) for me. Unless you want to.
But maybe you are familiar with the [vulkan-tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com) code base and have an Idea what might have caused it.

UPDATE:

I still haven't figured out the problem. But in an attempt to reproduce the problem with more concise code I rewrote everything from scratch but wasn't able to reproduce the problem. I have now added in all the features the faulty version had and it is still working fine.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] directly here.

Comment: The problem only shows once you have a rendering triangle with uniform buffers. Due to how verbose Vulkan is, this requires about 1.5k loc. Should I post that here?

Comment: Not 1.5k loc I admit. I also know about Vulkans verbosity. Hmm. OK. If you cannot shrink it (which I admit to be possible) then better not show all of it here. I recommend to hint at these things in your question however, because people here at StackOverflow are absolutely fans of direct MREs....